# Some update triggers are adding extra line EXECUTE sp_settriggerorder when deploying DB through DACPAC

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-data-tools

Please bear with my words. I am not sure how to explain this. I am seeing one more extra line after my trigger.

example:

```
if not exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where parent_obj=object_id('[dbo].[test]') and objectproperty(id,'test')=1 and xtype='TR')
begin
  exec sp_settriggerorder '[dbo].[tr_u_test]', 'Last', 'Update';
end
GO

-------------------------------------------- 
END of my Trigger.sql
------
--- not there in trigger sql but seeing in DB after the deploy. 
EXECUTE sp_settriggerorder @triggername = N'[dbo].[tr_u_test]', @order = N'last', @stmttype = N'update';
GO
```

This happened with multiple update triggers's but not all.

Please let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: It is common for logging triggers to be set to fire last. That allows other triggers that perform validation and the like to have an opportunity to roll back the transaction before it is logged by a trigger. FWIW, triggers can be set to fire first or last (only one of each) and all the others fire in an indeterminate order in between.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. but it is possible to avoid changes like this in when comparing with DB or DB projects. because this is making my list huge when comparing changes before release.